# creating a executable file or a bat for my selenium project

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

So I'm using Netbeans to write my selenium program and now that I've finish it I wanted to make it into a executable or bat file. I have the jar file and created the bat file with following information

```
java -jar jar_name.jar com.package_name.class_name
pause
```

I get this error when running the bat file

```
no main manifest attribute, jar_name.jar
```

I noticed most people are using maven but I didn't create the project with that in mind. I feel like I'm missing something that should be obvious.

Comment: you need MANIFEST.MF file and main class that is entry point of the application , see here on how to generate https://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html#Exercise_1

Comment: I would still suggest to convert this project to maven project, it's not difficult. some ide rather has shortcut to convert existing project to maven.